# Enable/disable Chrome extensions per site (via white or blacklist)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, extension

Is it possible to create a black or whitelist for Chrome extensions that works per site?
I find there's a few extensions that I find extremely useful on some sites, but clash with others.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you don't mind installing an extra extension, this might be useful: [Extension Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension-manager/gjldcdngmdknpinoemndlidpcabkggco)

I was looking for a solution to the same problem. I only need to disable the extension on a single domain, whitelisting all other domains would not be a good idea. So I found this extension allows you to create rules, which you can use it as a blacklist.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKhzV.png)

Comment: This is the extension I used to use but you could only white list before. This is perfect.

Comment: I looked at the source code for this extension, and it seems really hinky to me. Minified to the point of obfuscation, has a reference to doubleclick.net, has code to find ftp/https/mailto links, and, weirdly, has some kind of url-creating functionality that works differently 1% of the time (via random number) when it's called. I'm not a web dev, but it does all kinds of stuff that isn't related to managing extensions, and I feel like it's just too suspicious.

Comment: So, IIUC, Extension Manager can turn extensions off when I visit a blacklisted site but it disables the extension for all tabs (I guess that makes sense)... so would I use this to say disable risky extensions on a banking website until I close the banking tab after which all extensions are once again enabled?

Comment: It doesn't re-enable the extension on other tabs, even after you close the blacklisted tab. So this seems basically useless to me.

Comment: When you use `Disable Only` for `Ext_AA` on `foo.com` on this `Extension Manager` extension, \ 
it disables the extension `Ext_AA` for ALL TABS (the whole Chrome window), as long as you have a SINGLE tab of `foo.com` open....

Answer (score 19):

As of January 2021, Chrome 88 only lets you run extensions in 3 modes:

- On click
- On specific sites (i.e. a whitelist / allow-list)
- On all sites

Unfortunately **there is no built-in way to set a block-list of sites for an extension** (i.e.. "On all sites *except...*").

Comment: Dai is correct.  Not only is it assinine, but even worse Google hasn't bothered to update their documentation, which still walks step by step through screens that no longer (as of Chrome 88) even exist.

Comment: how do I undo  a permission given viw on click?

Comment: @user1050755 You will need to reload the page. You cannot revoke permission once an extension has been given access to a page (because once permission is granted, it can modify the page and add scripts and whatnot without needing the extension to run again).

Comment: ok, only works for me when restarting the browser. silly.

Comment: Is there any feedback page for chroimium where ideas/ feature requests can be shared (like connect.mozilla.org for firefox or the uservoice pages for man products)? Blacklisting would be really important in my opinion.

Comment: @SearchSpace Submit it as an issue: https://issues.chromium.org/issues - but don't hold your breath - it often takes years for even first-party suggestions to get closed as _wontfix_

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you you can modify what sites different extensions can run on by the following (some extensions cannot be bound to specific sites e.g., Google Docs):

On your computer, open Chrome.

At the top right, click the three stacked dots, 'More tools' and then 'Extensions'.

On the extension, click 'Details'.

Under 'Permissions', you can **add** or **remove** a site:

**Add**: Change 'Allow this extension to read and change all your data on websites that you visit' to 'On specific sites'.

Type the URL of the specific site you want it to run on, then click 'Add'. You can add more URL's by clicking 'Add a new page' once you have added a URL.

**Remove**: To the right of the site you have added, tap 'More' and then 'Remove' if you would like to remove its access to the site.

**You can also set  'Allow this extension to read and change all your data on websites that you visit' to 'On click', so that the extension will run only when you click it.**

**Also, no matter what website you are on, you can always temporarily reactivate the extension by clicking on it, then clicking 'Reload'.**

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Blacklist would have been better, but this will work for now. Thanks :)

Comment: I cannot see "add" nor "remove" under 'Permissions'.

Comment: Is there a way or set of URL patterns in to allow it on all websites, but specify exceptions? I just want to black-list certain websites on which a certain plugin causes trouble.

Comment: 2022 I don't see "Allowed sites"

Comment: What does "temporarily reactivate" mean? What makes it "temporary"? Did you mean "by RIGHT-clicking on it, then clicking 'Reload'"? I do not see "Reload" in any case.

Comment: This ability seems to be gone in Chrome now. There is a flag `Extensions Menu Access Control` which will allow to turn off all extensions / specific extension per site through the extension menu, HOWEVER as of the writing of this comment, it is very buggy and crashes frequently

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to enable an extension on a per-site basis without having to enter any site urls.

1. n/a
2. Right-click on the extension button.
3. Click "This can read and change site data ->"
4. Click "When you click the extension"
5. Restart Chrome.
6. Browse to a site where you want the extension enabled.
7. Click the extension button. The extension is now active.
8. Browse to a site where you DON'T want the extension enabled.
9. DON'T click the extension button. The extension is NOT active.

Unfortunately, Chrome will forget the per-site preferences next time you restart Chrome.